# Access GUI elements using AutoIt

Tags: windows, user-interface, autoit

Is it possible to access elements of a GUI in Windows directly using AutoIt? For example pressing a special button by handle and window title.

Is that possible and if it is, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is one of main features of AutoIt. But not all window elements can be processed. [AutoIt Window Information Tool](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm) allows to identify class of window/control:

[image]

For example type `89+12` in calc.exe:

```
run("calc.exe")
$calc = winwait("Калькулятор")
ControlClick($calc,"","Button9")
sleep(500)
ControlClick($calc,"","Button14")
sleep(500)
ControlClick($calc,"","Button23")
sleep(500)
ControlClick($calc,"","Button5")
sleep(500)
ControlClick($calc,"","Button11")
sleep(500)
ControlClick($calc,"","Button28")
```